# What is the correct datatype to store "Worked Hours"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am collecting the **Worked Hours** from users, the format will be like:

```
1:30
0:45
2:15
8:00
6:19
```

In SQL SERVER, what kinda of datatype should I use to store that value? I will need to sum this value in some point.

Comment: you are not really saving worked hours but worked minutes. Save worked time in minutes in an `int` field and convert it into `hh:mm` format as and when required for display purposes

Comment: If the user can't work more then 24 hours, then you can simply use `Time`. if they can work more then 24 hours, I would go with a small int that will be the number of minutes (1440 for every 24 hours)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - you still can't add two `time` values together though, so I'm not sure what benefit it would have.

Comment: Why not using start / end times ? You can DATEDIFF minutes out and format them as needed.

Comment: Horia, I don´t want the user to type the start and end. I just want the worked hours.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you have a good point there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not store worked hours, store worked minutes. Your values would become

```
Time int
---- ---
1:30 90
0:45 45
2:15 135
8:00 480
6:19 379
```

You will be able to convert it to display as necessary by dividing by 60 and taking the remainder.

Summing, on the other hand, will be very easy.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server unfortunately doesn't have a data type that represents a *time span*<sup>1</sup>. I would normally suggest an `int` column and a bit of naming so that it's clear that it's in seconds/minutes/hours - whatever the granularity is that you require.

---

<sup>1</sup>It has a `time` data type but that represents a time of day, not a time span. It doesn't make sense to add two times of day together, and this being so, the `time` data type doesn't support addition.